# Angular multiple parameter, passing as string to nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i am using angular & nodejs.
From angular i am passing multiple parameters to controlller & then to node to execute but it passing as a string in name-pare value like:`{"jobCarrierName":"rmg"}`
i need only it's value i.e "rmg".

```
<button style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5%;" title="Create File"
                        ng-click="createFile_Request({jobCarrierName : row.Carrier},{jobFileType : row.filetype})">
                    <strong>Create</strong></button>




$scope.createFile_Request = function (jobCarrierName, jobFileType) {

            $scope.jobName = jobCarrierName;
            $scope.jobFile = jobFileType;

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '../fileCreate/',
                params: {"carrier": $scope.jobName, "filetype": $scope.jobFile},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
                .success(function (data, status) {
                    alert(data.toString());
                   console.log("File Create Response");
                })
                .error(function (data, status) {
                    alert("Error in Creating File");
                });
        };
```

*NodeJs*

```
app.get("/fileCreate", function (req, res){

    var carrier = req.query.carrier;
    var filetype = req.query.filetype;
```

Comment: what problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: May be because of you are passing json on button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to parse your query string like this:

```
app.get("/fileCreate", function (req, res){
    req.query = JSON.parse(req.query);
    var carrier = req.query.carrier;
    var filetype = req.query.filetype;
```

**EDIT:**

Or maybe in your AngularJS file, you have to set your jobName like this :

```
$scope.jobName = jobCarrierName.jobCarrierName;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it's worked, I have forgotten this. thanks :) 
jobCarrierName.jobCarrierName